# Mobile Browser Usage Statistics

Tags: mobile, browsers, statistics

I'm looking  for global mobile browsers usage statistics from time to time compared to desktop browsers. Any better ideas than http://gs.statcounter.com/ ?

I need it as a reference for my college paper.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must understand that **it doesn't exist such list**.

There are many like statcounter, but what they provide is mobile browser usage for the sites they own or the sites that use their app or the sites that are searched through their site, and that's not global at all no matter how much effort they put in.

For example statcounter is based [according to their FAQ](http://gs.statcounter.com/faq#methodology) on their network of +3million sites and 15billion pageviews, it sound's a lot but it's not. It's an average of 5K pageviews per site, and [according to google](http://www.google.com/adplanner/static/top1000/index.html) that's just 1.5% of Facebook pageviews, or 62.5% of craiglist site traffic.

So keep this in mind when doing your research: no one has the truth and it's always relative to the people patterns among their traffic. I bet facebook mobile browsers stats won't have any relationship to History channel mobile browsers stats.

Here is a list of other sources (besides good @Guisasso answer):

1. http://www.netmarketshare.com
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers
3. http://www.akamai.com/html/io/index1.html

From all of those, likely Akamai would have the most accurate results in my experience, as they are the leading CDN used by most big companies and according to them, they handle 20% of internet web traffic.

Good luck with your research!

Comment: Looking around found wikimedia traffic report for last august: http://stats.wikimedia.org/archive/squid_reports/2012-08/SquidReportClients.htm

Answer (score 0):

W3 http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_mobile.asp ?

Comment: those stats are skewed towards their target audience of developers